# How to subtract value from the result of previous calculation

Tags: excel

it's kinda basic, but I don't even know how to formulate problem correctly. So please kindly help.

The task is:
I have a starting value A1 and a step value B1.
I subtract B1 from A1 and put a value into A2.
This is done by

```
=sum(A1-B1)
```

But then I need to subtract B1 from the result in A2 and so on.
That can be done by

```
=sum(A2-B1)
```

I wonder, what is the way to write a self adjusting formula or, at least, how such functionality would be called, so I can learn it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *absolute addressing* to "lock in" the address `B1` by prepending the row/column with a `$`:

```
=A2-$B$1
```

This will allow you to copy the formula across; Excel will automatically update the `A2` portion but keep the `$B$1` constant.

In this case, it looks like you're copying down, an absolute *row* is most likely what you want (i.e. `=A2-B$1`)

P.S. You know you're not `SUM`ming anything here, right?

Comment: When writing the formula you can use the shortcut ```F4``` to add the $ automatically. You can also only fix the column OR the row. This will only keep one of them fixed. E.g. ```B$2``` will only fix the row to ```2```

Comment: To show a math-solution to this without `$` in A3: `=2*A2-A1` and copy down... (but thats dumb and a just4fun solution, which no1 would use) :D stil: for what reason the `SUM`?

Comment: @DirkReichel - I was baffled by the fact that many people click what they call the "formula" button on the ribbon if they want to enter a formula. They don't know how to start a formula manually, so they click "Autosum" and then put the formula between the brackets. Shudder, but true.

Comment: @DirkReichel You know what, my brain didn't even register that `SUM` there and focused on the problem at hand. Thanks. And yeah, math works too :)

Comment: @teylyn I shudder too when I see it. And no matter how many times I tell them "you know you don't need that `SUM` there," they keep doing it, too!

Comment: I was wondering that myself! )) I don't know where I've got this pattern and I don't press any button) I've just used to write `=SUM(` every time. Happy to get rid of this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make B1 absolute.

In A2 enter this formula

`=A1-$B$1`

Then drag the formula down.